# How do I preserve ownership permissions when copying to an external volume?

Tags: linux, backup, permissions

When I upgrade or reinstall linux I backup my home folder by running `sudo cp -pr /home/users/yitzchak /media/externalHDD/backups`. When I do this I get errors saying that permissions could not be preserved and when I copy the folder back onto my local disk I see that ownership has been changed to root and I have to `chown` all of them back, which has to be done manually piecemeal because not all files have the same group. Is there any way around that?

Comment: I don't think this has to do with it being an external volume.  More likely it is the file system of the volume (probably fat32 or some other file system that does not support all attributes).  tar, cpio and other archiving utilities will preserve attributes if you don't need direct access as do some version control systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to archive the files during these backups, even without compression:

```
tar cf /media/externalHDD/backups/yitzchak.tar /home/users/yitzchak
```

`tar` will keep all the file attributes.